# Laravel 8 Register user while logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two tables with users, one for public users and one for workers. The workers can only be created by other workers, but when I go to the workers registration url, it detects that I am logged in and redirects me to home, how can I change this behavior?

I have tried commenting out part of the handle function in the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file but this causes users to be able to visit the login links while logged in.

Function I commented in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    // foreach ($guards as $guard) {
    //     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    //         return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    //     }
    // }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I would add other routes to handle adding new users/workers for authenticated users and keep the register routes for guests.

Comment: Don't make multiple tables for different types of users, keep a single users table with a `type` field that lets you distinguish between `public` and `workers`. Creation of additional `users` once authenticated should be done via a custom form/route and not the `register` page.

Comment: @Unflux Thanks, I'm trying that, but in the construct for registration what way can I change ```$this->middleware('auth');``` so that the user is of a type.

Comment: @JorgeMontejo Hopefully my answer below can enlighten you a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `users` table, define a field which will allow you to diferentiate between `types` of user.

```
$table->string('type')->default('public');
```

I've defined a field of `data type` `string` and given the field a default value of `public`. There are other ways you could do this such as making the `data type` an `integer` and using a lookup table, but lets keep things simple for now and to be honest it really doesn't matter.

The `type` will then be accessible on your `user` objects; `$user->type`.

To get the `type` for the currently authenticated `user`, you would use either `auth()->user()->type` or `Auth::user()->type` (doesn't matter which, same result).

Based on the value of `type` you would allow or deny access to something. In your case you want to deny users that are not of `type` `worker` from creating users of `type` `worker`.

Don't reuse the `register` form to create new users, create yourself a new scaffold (route, controller, view etc.) for this task. A basic of example of what this could look like below.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::resource('users', \App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class);
});
```

**resources/views/users/create.blade.php**

```
@if ($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif

<form action="{{ route('admin.users.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf

    {{--
        If the authenticated user is of type public
        you can choose to either hide the option for choosing a user type
    --}}

    @if (auth()->user()->type != 'public')
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="public">Public</option>
        <option value="worker">Worker</option>
    </select>
    @endif

    {{--
        Or you can simply disable it
    --}}

    <select name="type" id="type" @if (auth()->user()->type == 'public') disabled @endif>
        <option value="public">Public</option>
        <option value="worker">Worker</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

**app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('users.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // perform some validation on the data coming in
        // the value of the type field should be either public or worker
        // other values should cause an error

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'type' => ['in:public,worker']
        ]);

        // an additional check to prevent non workers creating worker users
        // this could be extracted to a custom validation rule

        if (auth()->user()->type != 'worker' && $request->type == 'worker') {
            return redirect(route('admin.users.create')
                ->withErrors([
                    'unauthorised' => 
                        'You do not have authorisation to create users of type Worker'
                )]
                ->withInput();
        }

        // Don't forget to add 'type' to the $fillable array on your user model

        User::create($validator->validated());

        return redirect(route('users.admin.create')->with(['success' => 'User created!')];
    }
}
```

The above is a very basic implementation to point you in the right direction. You could extract the functionality for checking if a `user` is a `worker` into a [`middleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware), create [`gates`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates) and [`custom validation rules`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) to make things more reusable.

Comment: Thank you! it really helps me. One question, is there any way to use ```Auth::user()->type```` directly on a route? I had thought about an if in the group routes function, I don't know if it would be the right way.

Comment: @JorgeMontejo Yes, you would create a custom middleware that checks the user `type` and then you would apply that middleware to your route(s).